# Does AWS APIGateway generated SDK and Swift 4.0?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, swift4

I had a working Swift project under v3.2 working with the AWS APIGateway generated SDK.  However, I tried converting to Swift 4.0 and now it returns no results and no errors.

Is this just unsupported currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found my answer on github:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/744

The relevant quote is below and there is no response on when Swift 4 will be supported.

> Currently the generated SDK is Swift 3 only.

Update #1:
I found this some time ago that provides a workaround to this problem:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/750#issuecomment-337046816

> This is happening due to change in @objc inference. See change:
>   SE-0160
>
> What this implies is, the properties in Swift class are no longer
>   visible to ObjectiveC code and we need to explicitly make them
>   available. The current work around for Swift 4 would be to either have
>   @obj declaration before the properties to be mapped for dynamo db
>   table or declare all properties to be visible to ObjectiveC using
>   @objcMembers
>
> Example:
>
> Class level: @objcMembers class MyTable: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel,
>   AWSDynamoDBModeling {
>
> ```
> var hashKey: String?
> var attribute1: NSNumber?
>
> public static func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
>     return "MyTableName"
> }
>
> public static func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
>     return "hashKey"
> }
>  } or
> ```
>
> Attribute level: class MyTable: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel,
>   AWSDynamoDBModeling {
>
> ```
> @objc var hashKey: String?
> @objc var attribute1: NSNumber?
>
> public static func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
>     return "MyTableName"
> }
>
> public static func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
>     return "hashKey"
> }
>  }
> ```

I will investigate further to see if we can mitigate this issue some other way.